# Why out of range?

Tags: python, range

Could someone please tell me why I get this error?

```
result[i][j+1]=X[i][j]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
def  matrixTranspose(X):
    result=[[0 for k in range (len(X))] for l in range (len(X[0]))]
    for i in range(len(X)):
        for  j in range (len(X[0])):
            result[i][j+1]=X[i][j]
    return result


m1=[]
r=input("enter The no. of rows:")
c=input("enter The no. of columns:")
s=[[0 for i in range (c)]for j in range (r)]
for i in range (r):
row=[]
for j in range (c):
    x=input("Enter Value")
    row.append(x)
m1.append(row)


print m1
m2=matrixTranspose(m1)
print m2
```

Comment: I think the canonical solution for transposing a matrix would be `zip(*X)`. But I understand the need to get your own version working for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't index `result` at `len(X[0])+1`, because its dimensions are `len(X)` by `len(X[0])`. Also your `matrixTranpose` function doesn't seem to be taking the transpose of `X`. Presumably you mean:

```
def  matrixTranspose(X):
    result=[[0 for k in range (len(X))] for l in range (len(X[0]))]
    for i in range(len(X)):
        for  j in range (len(X[0])):
            result[j][i]=X[i][j]
    return result
```

Comment: Well what if i want to rotate the matrix by 90 degrees??

Comment: That's not the transpose. If you want to rotate a matrix by 90 degrees, There are plenty of answers on this site alone telling you how to do that.